# Checkbox changing state when scrolling in recyclerview

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I made a small app that shows me a list of all the apps installed to my phone I want to add a check box to every cardview so that I can mark my favorite apps and other classification. The problem is when scrolling through the list the state of the checkbox change ex. I checked chrome and when I scrolled down then scrolled up chrome is not marked and a random app is checked. I searched for other question related to this problem but none of those solutions worked for me.

updated version of appsadapter.java

```
 public class AppsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppsAdapter.ViewHolder>{
private final SparseBooleanArray array=new SparseBooleanArray();

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public CardView cardView;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView textView_App_Name;
    public CheckBox checkBox;

    public ViewHolder (View view){

        super(view);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chckbox);
        cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        textView_App_Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Apk_Name);
        //textView_App_Package_Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Apk_Package_Name);

    }
}

private Context context1;
private List<String> stringList;

public AppsAdapter(Context context, List<String> list){

    context1 = context;
    stringList = list;
}

//viewholder initialized
@Override
public AppsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

    View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(context1).inflate(R.layout.cardview_layout,parent,false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view2);
    return viewHolder;
}

//DATA IS BOUND TO VIEWS
private SparseBooleanArray sba = new SparseBooleanArray();
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder,final int position){

    viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    ApkInfoExtractor apkInfoExtractor = new ApkInfoExtractor(context1);
    final String ApplicationPackageName = (String) stringList.get(position);

    //calling apps name and icon
    String ApplicationLabelName = apkInfoExtractor.GetAppName(ApplicationPackageName);
    Drawable drawable = apkInfoExtractor.getAppIconByPackageName(ApplicationPackageName);

    //setting app name and icon for every card
    viewHolder.textView_App_Name.setText(ApplicationLabelName);
    viewHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sba.put(position, !sba.get(position));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(sba.get(position));


    /*Adding click listener on CardView to open clicked application directly from here
    viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = context1.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(ApplicationPackageName);
            if(intent != null){
                context1.startActivity(intent);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(context1,ApplicationPackageName + " Error, Please Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });*/
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return stringList.size();
}
```

}

Comment: try adding this line in activity just before setting adapter to your recylerview `mRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(yourList.size());`

Comment: @MohammedFarhan what for can you explain to what this line will do?

Comment: RecylerView recyles same view after every 9 items. So if the dataSet you are passing to adapter has more than 9 items and changes made to particular item(checking checkbox) will reappear after 9 item.
So if you add that line it will `Set the number of offscreen views to retain before adding them to the potentially shared recycled view pool. The offscreen view cache stays aware of changes in the attached adapter.`

Answer (score 5):

That is because **in the recycler view, item views are re used** to show new data. You have to add a variable in your data item that holds the state of the checkbox at a particular position. Then in the `onBindViewHolder` you can check the value of the tracking variable and set the state of the checkbox like `yourCheckbox.setchecked(item.getSelected())` set the tracking variable value in the `onCheckChanged` method

Comment: Hi! Can you show me a simple code that I can follow? Sorry for disturbing you

Answer (score 1):

set view `onclicklistener` in `BindViewholder` method so you can use the current position of item as in

```
 private SparseBooleanArray sba = new SparseBooleanArray();
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder,final int position){

        viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        ApkInfoExtractor apkInfoExtractor = new ApkInfoExtractor(context1);
        final String ApplicationPackageName = (String) stringList.get(position);

        //calling apps name and icon
        String ApplicationLabelName = apkInfoExtractor.GetAppName(ApplicationPackageName);
        Drawable drawable = apkInfoExtractor.getAppIconByPackageName(ApplicationPackageName);

        //setting app name and icon for every card
        viewHolder.textView_App_Name.setText(ApplicationLabelName);
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    sba.put(position,!sba.get(position));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(sba.get(position));
    }
```

Comment: hello sir! I use your code and its giving an error saying 'local variable postion is accessed from with in inner class, needs to be declared final' so I changed int position to final int position to solve the error but the the checkbox issue is still there.

Comment: The issue is still there. Adding the final removes the error from the code but the state of the checkbox is is still changing.

Comment: I replaced the code with this and its having an error that says 'put(int,    boolean)in SparceBooleanArray cannot be applied to (boolean)'

Comment: Didn't solve the problem. the checkbox is still chaging state

Comment: glad I could help ! Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hello again sir, I just noticed that the problem is still there,  I thought its gone but the checkbox is still changing their states.

Answer (score 0):

Set checkbox inside checkBox onclickListener

```
holder.mCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view;
            mDataModel = (DataModel) checkBox.getTag();
            mDataModel.setChecked(checkBox.isChecked());
            arrayList.get(position).setChecked(checkBox.isChecked());

        }
    });
```